# WP_Query order by two values

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Im trying to make WP_Query to order by two different values, but i cant figure how to do this. Im trying to get events in one query by ending time. There is custom ending_date_time field in every event with datetime of value YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s. I need query to get values so first one is event that is closest to ending and so on, and if there is events that have ended, they come after those events that havent end yet.

With MySQL i would do this kind of thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_endtime < NOW(), event_endtime ASC
```

Comment: From the codex page: "orderby (string | array) - Sort retrieved posts by parameter. Defaults to 'date (post_date)'. **One or more options can be passed**. ". As for [ordering by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value): you need a `meta_key=ending_date_time` in your query, and then your `orderby` parameter should be set to `meta_value`. I'm unsure whether you must order ASC or DESC to have to closest dates first - maybe just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

With this query you get the events for the now and in the future.

```
$today = date( 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s' );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'orderby'   => 'event_endtime',
     'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_endtime',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
):
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you want to past events you have to change  `'compare' => '<='`.